# C++ reading input from text file with delimiters into arrays (plural)

Tags: c++, arrays, delimiter, getline

I am trying to read in a text file with input similar to this:

s 12

r 2

e 15

Pattern: random letter, space, random number.

I am wanting to store the random letters in one array and then store the random numbers in a separate array.

I have spent a good amount of time trying to get this to work but I am really stuck.

Right now I have a program that reads in just the random letters, then outputs the contents of the array (which for some reasons doesn't output element 0).

So my question is, how does one read the text file while storing the letters in one array while the numbers in a different array?

The following is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main () {

string line;
ifstream myfile ("freq.txt");

if (myfile.is_open()){

    string stringArray[1024];
    int intArray[1024];

    int stringPosition = 0;
    int intPosition = 0;

    while (getline(myfile, line)){

        getline(myfile, stringArray[stringPosition], ' ');
        //getline(myfile, intArray[intPosition], ' ');
        stringPosition++;
        intPosition++;
    }

    myfile.close();

    for (int i=0; i<stringPosition; i++)
        cout << stringArray[i] << ' ' << intArray[i] << endl;

}

else cout << "Unable to open file";

return 0;
}
```

**Problem has been resolved thanks to Igor**

Comment: Why not just `char letter; int number; while (myfile >> letter >> number) { stringArray[stringPosition++] = letter; intArray[intPosition++] = number; }` Better still, use `std::vector` for your two arrays.

Comment: What an elegant way to handle this problem..  Thank you Igor!  I was unaware of the myfile>> option.  Problem has been resolved!!